# Why do Chazal refer to the emergence of a baby from the womb as pesichas hakever

Tags: words, women, pregnancy-birth, cemetery-grave

A term throughout *Chazal* is פתיחת הקבר, *pesichas hakever*, translated literally as the opening of the grave. For example, [Niddah 21a](https://www.sefaria.org/Niddah.21a.19?vhe=Wikisource_Talmud_Bavli&lang=bi). This term refers to the emergence of a fetus or baby from the womb ([Rashi ad. loc.](https://www.sefaria.org/Rashi_on_Niddah.21a.19.1?lang=bi), Aruch § קבר [1]).

Why did Chazal refer to the womb, רחם, as a קבר, a grave?

Answer (score 3):

Refer to the Gemoro in [Sanhedrin 92a](https://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.92a.22?lang=bi):

> אמר ר' טבי אמר ר' יאשיה מאי דכתיב (משלי ל, טז) שאול ועוצר רחם ארץ לא שבעה מים וכי **מה ענין שאול אצל רחם אלא לומר לך מה רחם מכניס ומוציא אף שאול מכניס ומוציא**
>
> § The Gemara returns to the topic of the source for resurrection in the Torah. Rabbi Tavi says that Rabbi Yoshiya says: What is the meaning of that which is written: “There are three that are never satisfied…the grave, and the barren womb, and earth that does not receive sufficient water” (Proverbs 30:15–16)? And what does a grave have to do with a womb? Rather, they are juxtaposed to say to you: **Just as a womb takes in and gives forth, so too a grave takes in and also gives forth, with the resurrection of the dead**. (Sefaria translation and notation)

Alternatively, the womb is to be seen as a child's "ticket" out to the world. Providing it is open, there is access to the world but once closed that's it. It can be seen an expression that is relevant to the unfortunate circumstance where there is a still birth. In such a situation the child is essentially born dead and thus the womb is its grave - For example, refer to the Mishnah in [Ohalos 7:4](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Oholot.7.4?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)

Building on this line of thinking, we can quote [Yirmiyahu 20:17](https://www.sefaria.org/Jeremiah.20.17?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), where it writes:

> אֲשֶׁ֥ר לֹא־מוֹתְתַ֖נִי מֵרָ֑חֶם וַתְּהִי־לִ֤י אִמִּי֙ קִבְרִ֔י וְרַחְמָ֖הֿ הֲרַ֥ת עוֹלָֽם
>
> Because he did not kill me before birth so that my mother might be my grave, and her womb big [with me] for all time.

Radak writes there the following:

> שאם מותתני קודם צאתי מרחם היתה לי אמי קברי
>
> That if I was dead before I came out of the womb that my mother would be my grave.

Comment: And see Rashi on Mishlei 30:16 where he says that just as a grave is never sated with corpses, nor is the corridor to the womb, nor the earth with water.

Comment: So call it שאול? Nice connection though.

Comment: @Shmuel Rashi on the Gemara in Sanhedrin says the same thing

Comment: @Robev - see my second answer

Comment: @Dov Yeah, I quoted it from the ArtScroll Sanhedrin. It there quotes Rashi on 30:16.

Comment: @robev - as far as the first answer if you look at Rashi there - Rashi uses the word Kever and not She'ol